# Make functions an instance of vector type class

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I have a custom type class for mathematical vectors

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Vector v a where

    infixl 6 <+>
    (<+>) :: v -> v -> v  -- vector addition

    infixl 6 <->
    (<->) :: v -> v -> v  -- vector subtraction

    infixl 7 *>
    (*>)  :: a -> v -> v  -- multiplication by a scalar

    dot   :: v -> v -> a  -- inner product
```

and I want to make numbers `a` and functions `a -> vector` into an instance of the class. Numbers are easy:

```
instance Num a => Vector a a where
    (<+>) = (+)
    (<->) = (-)
    (*>)  = (*)
    dot   = (*)
```

and I thought functions would also be easy (well, except for `dot`, but I can live with that)

```
instance Vector b c => Vector (a -> b) c where
    f <+> g = \a -> f a <+> g a
    f <-> g = \a -> f a <-> g a
    c *>  f = \a -> c *> f a
    dot     = undefined
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
  (Vector b a0) arising from a use of `<+>'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: f a <+> g a
In the expression: \ a -> f a <+> g a
In an equation for `<+>': f <+> g = \ a -> f a <+> g a
```

How can I tell GHC that the instance is valid for *all* types `a`? Where am I supposed to add the type signature?

Comment: It might be impossible this way, after all instances of `Vector b c` with different `c` might have different behaviour of `<+>`, even though `c` doesn't actually turn up in the signature of that function. — Are you deliberately avoiding fundeps (or type families) or making a seperate `additiveGroup` class? [vectorspace](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.3) actually does _both_ of this, there's certainly a reason.

Comment: No, I'm not deliberately avoiding them. Making an additive group class certainly seems sensible. I'll investigate fundeps and report back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type families are definitely the loveliest way of solving this problem

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-} 
class VectorSpace v where
    type Field v

    infixl 6 <+>
    (<+>) :: v -> v -> v  -- vector addition

    infixl 6 <->
    (<->) :: v -> v -> v  -- vector subtraction

    infixl 7 *>
    (*>)  :: Field v -> v -> v  -- multiplication by a scalar

    dot   :: v -> v -> Field v  -- inner product
```

Mathematically, to make a vector space out of functions, you have to reuse the same field:

```
instance VectorSpace b => VectorSpace (a -> b) where
    type Field (a -> b) = Field b
    f <+> g = \a -> f a <+> g a
    f <-> g = \a -> f a <-> g a
    c *>  f = \a -> c *> f a
    dot     = error "Can't define the dot product on functions, sorry."
```

...and the nice thing about type families is that they work very much how you would explain.
Let's make the direct product of two vector spaces:

```
instance (VectorSpace v,VectorSpace w, Field v ~ Field w,Num (Field v)) => VectorSpace (v,w) where
    type Field (v,w) = Field v
    (v,w) <+> (v',w') = (v <+> v',w <+> w')
    (v,w) <-> (v',w') = (v <-> v',w <-> w')
    c *> (v,w) = (c *> v, c*> w)
    (v,w) `dot` (v',w') = (v `dot` v') + (w `dot` w')
```

You could replace the `Num` context with a custom algebraic class, but `Num` captures the concept 
of a Field moderately well.

Comment: Thanks. This is remarkably similar to the code that I wrote after reading the source of the vector-space package!

Comment: I guess I should have read it too. Conal has made `dot` part of a separate class, so that not all Vector Speces have to have one. That makes a lot of sense, so you don't have `dot = undefined` lying around in your code.

Comment: Yup, it definitely makes sense to have separate classes for AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace and InnerSpace. Well done, Conal.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make the following small example (patterned after Conal Elliott's [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) package) compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Main
       where

class Vector v where
  type Scalar v

  infixl 6 <+>
  (<+>) :: v -> v -> v  -- vector addition

  infixl 7 *>
  (*>)  :: (Scalar v) -> v -> v  -- multiplication by a scalar

instance Vector v => Vector (a -> v) where
  type Scalar (a -> v) = (a -> Scalar v)
  f <+> g = \a -> f a <+> g a
  (*>) c f  = \a -> c a *> f a -- Can't deduce that Scalar v ~ Scalar (a -> v)
```

It may be possible to make this work with functional dependencies instead of type families.

Comment: Thanks - I've just been reading the source for vector-space myself and was going to try TypeFamilies :)