# Multi-parameter typeclass instance declarations

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand multiparameter typeclasses but I just don't get the instance declarations. I am starting out trying to make an InnerProductSpace typeclass for a Vector type so that I can perform a dot product on two vectors. To start out I just wanted to see if I could multiply the first element of each vector. Here is my code

```
class InnerProductSpace a b c where
dot :: a -> b -> c

data Vector = Vector [Double]
  deriving (Show)

instance InnerProductSpace Vector Vector Double where
  dot (Vector a) (Vector b) = (head a * head b)
```

and the error after trying to use the dot function is

```
No instance for (InnerProductSpace Vector Vector c0)
  arising from a use of `dot'
The type variable `c0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance InnerProductSpace Vector Vector Double
    -- Defined at Vector.hs:8:10
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (InnerProductSpace Vector Vector c0)
In the expression: dot a b
In an equation for `it': it = dot a b
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Multi-parameter type classes are full of conceptual hurdles, whereas type families work like functions at the type level, so are easier. Have a look at my answer to someone with a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13035800/1598537) and how I suggest they use type families to deal with vector spaces.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know how to choose the right instance given what it knows. If you try something like

```
vectorA `dot` vectorA
```

the compiler goes searching for the right `dot` knowing that its type must be `dot :: Vector -> Vector -> c0`. Unfortunately, that's just not enough information by itself—`c0` could be anything and the compiler never assumes that just because it only has a single instance it must be the *correct* one (this is related to the open world assumption---there *might* be another instance out there the compiler hasn't seen yet, so it prefers to just throw an error). You could get away with it by explicitly telling the compiler what the result ought to be

```
vectorA `dot` vectorB :: Double
```

but this is tedious and likely to fail a lot with numeric types since so often those types are generic as well. For instance, which instance of `Num` is used here?

```
(vectorA `dot` vectorB) + 3
```

We know it's `Double`, but the compiler can't *prove* that.

One solution is to use Type Families as @AndrewC suggests in the comment. I actually highly recommend that. The other solution you'll see in the wild is Functional Dependencies. These are written like this

```
class InnerProductSpace a b c | a b -> c where
  dot :: a -> b -> c
```

and translate to entail a promise to the compiler: "knowing `a` and `b` is enough information to uniquely identify `c`". The compiler keeps you honest as well as it'll prevent you from writing instances that conflict on that promise.

```
instance InnerProductSpace Vector Vector Double where
  dot (Vector a) (Vector b) = (head a * head b)

instance InnerProductSpace Vector Vector Float where
  dot (Vector a) (Vector b) = (head a * head b)

---

/Users/tel/tmp/foo.hs:10:10:
    Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
      instance InnerProductSpace Vector Vector Double
        -- Defined at /Users/tel/tmp/foo.hs:10:10
      instance InnerProductSpace Vector Vector Float
        -- Defined at /Users/tel/tmp/foo.hs:13:10
```

But the promise gives the compiler exactly enough information to resolve the `Double` in the previous example.

```
Main*> (Vector [1,2,3]) `dot` (Vector [2,3,4]) + 3.0
5
```

Comment: Thanks! For now I'll stick to functional dependencies. That makes more sense to me at the moment. This is my first day with Haskell, so maybe tomorrow I'll be ready to tackle type families. ;-)

Comment: should that not be knowing a and b is enough information to uniquely identify c?

Answer (score 3):

or use TypeFamilies

```
class (D a b ~ c) => InnerProductSpace a b c where
  type D a b
  dot :: a -> b -> c
```

or

```
class InnerProductSpace a b where
  type D a b :: *
  dot :: a -> b -> D a b

instance InnerProductSpace Vector Vector where
  type D Vector Vector = Double
  dot (Vector a) (Vector b) = (head a * head b)
```